# use user32.dll in win ce5.0

Tags: c#, user32

I am trying to use sendmessage of user32.dll in an embedded windows ce5.0 computer
the same simple program that I made only for testing the user32 in embedded is working on my windows xp computer.
the app and the dll are in the same folder.

the message I get when it is in win ce5.0 is : Can't find Pinvocke DLL 'user32.dll'

the code : (I find it in the web and used it to try the sendmessage)

```
    private int SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170;
    private int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]

    private static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMessage(this.Handle.ToInt32(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);
    }
```

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

SendMessage is defined in coredll.dll in Windows CE. See this link:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.SendMessage

Answer (score 0):

Please see [**user32.dll** used instead of **coredll.dll** in **WINCE**](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/10189)